# Script to identify the files based on current date and file name pattern

Tags: bash, shell, date, csv, curl

There are 10 files located in different directory which contains date pattern in it. I need to pick these files one by one and send to remote site   I also thought to list the file naming pattern, location in config file and pick from the script from config file one by one but without any luck.

sample file name pattern and location

```
/documents/accounts/transfer/done/abc_yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm-ss-[0-9]{6}.csv
/documents/namelist/transfer/done/def_yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm-ss-[0-9]{6}.csv
/documents/newcustomer/transfer/done/ghijkl_yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm-ss-[0-9]{6}.csv
```

I have tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
date=`date +%Y-%m-%d`;
config_file="/scripts/config/abc.cfg"; 
echo $config_file; 
URL="http://localhost:9200/document-$date";
find /documents -type f -name "*_'${date}'*.csv" | while read filename
do
       echo "filename : ${filename}"
       var=$(base64 $filename| perl -pe 's/\n//g');
       var1= curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/documents-'$date'/document/?pipeline=attachment&pretty' -d' { "data" : "'$var'" }')  
done;
```

Can someone advise how best to do this?

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: find command did not picks any files if use above . But when i use *.csv then it picks all the files in the directory which i dont need and only that particular day files to be picked .

Comment: Can you provide an actual sample file name with proper date values in it? Your script won't work as it is looking for files with the current timestamp, you need a regex in find

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem with my solution?

Comment: You can use the script example from my answer at the last

Comment: there was a missing $ in the syntax, refer my latest update now.

Comment: Yes, i have corrected that already and tested . No syntax error expect the curl: Argumentlist is too long

Comment: The problem to that is beyond the scope of the this question. You can accept this answer, small tick on the left of my answer and ask that as a new question separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `find` command you can drop the single-quotes around the `date` variable as

```
find  -type f -name "*_${date}*.csv"
```

since the double-quotes `"` as such expand the value of variables in `bash` and you don't have to single quote again.

Demo:-

```
touch abc_2016-12-28-3523424-acsfsc.csv
touch abc_2016-12-29-3523424-acsfsc.csv
```

Confirming once the presence of the files without the `-name` filter

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print
./abc_2016-12-28-3523424-acsfsc.csv
./abc_2016-12-29-3523424-acsfsc.csv
```

Now setting the variable `date` to today's date as

```
date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
find  -type f -name "*_${date}*.csv"
./abc_2016-12-28-3523424-acsfsc.csv
```

Also do not use pipe-line to set variables in `bash`, use [process-substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) and use `-print0` for a more robust handling of files with special characters in the filenames.

```
while IFS='' read -r -d '' filename
do
    echo "filename : ${filename}"
    var=$(base64 "$filename"| perl -pe 's/\n//g');
    var1=$(curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/documents-$date/document/?pipeline=attachment&pretty" -d '{ "data" : "'"$var"'" }')
done < <(find -type f -name "*_${date}*.csv" -print0)
```